# Convert binary to hex and make operation

Tags: c

I am new to `C` and I have already tried many ways to convert `char*` variable which store `binary` representation into `hex` value.

The variable is for example:

```
0110110000001110110000010100111000110011110110110111000110111000
```

which stands for

```
6C 0E  C1 4E 33 DB  71 B8
```

where

```
0110- 6, 1100 - C, 0000 - 0, 1110 - E and so on...
```

However when I want to use `fprintf` format or `strtol`, which I found recommended for this kind of problems, I get:

```
char* lm_bin = "0110110000001110110000010100111000110011110110110111000110111000";
//convert to dec
int lm_dec = (int)strtol(lm_bin, NULL, 2);
char lm_hex[12];
//convert to hex
sprintf(lm_hex, "%x", lm_dec);
fprintf(stderr, "binary %s", lm_bin);
fprintf(stderr, "hex %s", lm_hex);
```

the output is:

> binary
>   0110110000001110110000010100111000110011110110110111000110111000 hex
>   33db71b8

which is not correct. Can anyone point me where I am making a mistake?

Comment: Why are you trying to squeeze 16 characters of hex into a 12 byte string, which can only really handle 11 characters plus a null terminator.  It also helps readability of output if you include newlines at appropriate points.  And you would probably do better with with `unsigned long long` and `strtoull()` — `int` won't hold 16 hex digits on most machines.

Comment: `int` is probably not wide enough. Your platform seems to have 32 bit `int`s and your input is 64 bits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why are you trying to squeeze 16 characters of hex into a 12 byte string, which can only really handle 11 characters plus a null terminator. It also helps readability of output if you include newlines at appropriate points. And you would probably do better with with `unsigned long long` and `strtoull()` — `int` won't hold 16 hex digits on most machines.  It is also conventional to write expected output on standard output; use standard error for error messages.

Putting those changes together yields an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char lm_bin[] = "0110110000001110110000010100111000110011110110110111000110111000";
    unsigned long long lm_dec = strtoull(lm_bin, NULL, 2);
    char lm_hex[17];
    sprintf(lm_hex, "%llx", lm_dec);
    printf("binary %s\n", lm_bin);
    printf("hex %s\n", lm_hex);
    return 0;
}
```

And the output from that is what you sought, I believe:

```
binary 0110110000001110110000010100111000110011110110110111000110111000
hex 6c0ec14e33db71b8
```

That code doesn't check for conversion errors and could use `snprintf()` instead of `sprintf()`, and could do all the printing in a single call to `printf()` — and doesn't need to use the string for the hex-formatted output (it could format `lm_dec` directly).  So, there's lots of room for changes and improvements in the code.

Comment: ahhh it is so much more to learn. I missed not only long long int but also long long hex. Naturally Your code works like charm. Thank You very much !